# removeObserverWithHandle does not seems to be working in fireBase iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am fetching the data from firebase and after that removing the observer. But if data gets changes at that location block is still gets called.

Code to fetch data :

```
  if messageCountDBReference == nil {
         messageCountDBReference = FireBaseReferenceFactory.messageListReference(forSericeId: serviceId)
    }

   messageCountDBHandle = messageCountDBReference!.observe(.value, with: { (dataSnapShot) in
/// data processing
```

})

In `ViewWillDisappear` removing observer.

```
if messageCountDBHandle != nil {
    messageCountDBReference?.removeObserver(withHandle: messageCountDBHandle!)
    }
    messageCountDBReference = nil
    messageCountDBHandle = nil
```

Answer (score 2):

You have put the `.removeObserver` in  `viewWillDisappear` that means that it will be removed just before the view is disappeared. So if you stay in that view for 10 minutes, and 100 changes happen in that Firebase path, it will display all 100 of them.

What you are looking for is `.observeSingleEvent` that reads data once and then removes the observer.

Comment: I want to observe the changes ,if I am on that screen,but if not there should not observe the changes. That block is getting called even if I am not on that screen.

Comment: how do you know that?

Comment: I put a break in that block and control is going there.

Comment: Then you are not removing the view from the hierarchy, you are probably just adding another one on top of it. If you notice, i said that the observer will be removed just before the view is disappeared, not just before is covered by another view. Show how you are dismissing that view.

Comment: I am clicking on back button of navigationBar.